# Can 'Eyes in the Dark' be played on an Investigator with a Torch?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

**Torch** *Investigators may Ignore Darkness in your room.*

**Eyes in the Dark: Requirement** Basement or *any room in darkness.*

We took the ruling that the mythos card could not target the investigator as he was ignoring the darkness token.

We felt that there was an argument that while the investigator was ignoring darkness, he was still in fact in a room that was dark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The investigator cannot be targeted by **Eyes in the Dark.**

The ruling you are looking for is on page 15 of the [rules](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/mansions-of-madness/support/MansionsOfMadnessLoRes.pdf):

> Some Exploration cards (such as the “Lantern”) allow 
>   investigators to ignore these effects. When ignoring these effects, 
>   an investigator also *cannot be targeted* by cards that require them 
>   to be in a room with a darkness token.